# What is the correct style/format when including Chinese translations in academic articles?

Tags: translation, mandarin, characters, academic

For instance, I would like to write the following sentence about China:

"Many songs were written to praise the Chinese Communist Party and the 'Motherland' ".

By "Motherland", I mean 祖国 ( zuguo / zŭguó).

This is an academic article, and I would like to include both the Chinese characters and the pinyin. What style should I use?

Answer (score 3):

If I'm writing a scholarly article I normally put the Chinese first (Pinyin italicized and before characters) like this:

> Many songs were written to praise the Chinese Communist Party and the *zǔguó* 祖国 ‘Motherland’.

The reason is that for a linguistically inclined and Chinese-reading audience I'd give primacy to Chinese term. But if it's intended for ordinary readers, I'd make the English the primary focus, this way:

> Many songs were written to praise the Chinese Communist Party and the ‘Motherland’ (*zǔguó* 祖国).

Comment: By the way — somewhat off-topic, so I relegate it to a comment — I think "motherland" is a poor translation for _zǔguó_ — I'd prefer "ancestral land" or Fatherland, myself.

Comment: 'Fatherland' makes me think of Nazi Germany, while 'Motherland' reminds of 'Mother Russia'. 'Ancestral land' doesn't sound like native English

Comment: "Fatherland" is close to what is used in most European languages, quite apart from the German case. Ancestral land is certainly good, standard English — and it matches the internal sense of the Chinese — so even if it's unfamiliar in this particular case I'd prefer it. One could also try "homeland", not quite as good.

Comment: "homeland" usually translate to 家园

Comment: I don't understand why "motherland" is inappropriate for 祖国. If that's what it should be in English, then we will have no reason to deny it.

Answer (score 0):

- Use normal vernacular, make it readable
- Omit tone marks in pinyin
- Do not reverse names in translation (as the Japanese do)

Comment: Omitting tone marks in Pinyin seems to me a serious error except in the case of familiar proper nouns. Tones are an integral part of the Chinese language and should be used regularly in Pinyin.

Comment: If you do not want people to know how the Chinese is pronounced, then omit pinyin altogether.  If you do want them to know, then use the tones. @brannerchinese is right, the only exception is Chinese names so common that they have been absorbed into English.

Comment: Those who can read Chinese characters will know how to pronounce them. Those who cannot read Chinese do not understand how to pronounce tones. Therefore, tones do not provide any useful information in this context.